# Extract text from a DOM element in javascript casperjs

Tags: javascript, casperjs

```
for(var i=0; i < 20; i++) { 

this.fetchText('div.ma-AdCardMyAds:nth-child('+i+') > div.one > div.two > div.three > span[class="ma-AdCard-price"]'));

}
```

There are occasions that before span there are 2 divs instead of 3 divs. I need to always reach span[class="ma-AdCard-price"] starting from div.ma-AdCardMyAds:nth-child('+1+')

Only div.one > div.three

```
this.fetchText('div.ma-AdCardMyAds:nth-child('+i+') > div.one > div.three > span[class="ma-AdCard-price"]'));
```

doesn't work

```
this.fetchText('div.ma-AdCardMyAds:nth-child('+i+') > span[class="ma-AdCard-price"]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
this.fetchText('div.ma-AdCardMyAds:nth-child('+i+') span[class="ma-AdCard-price"]')
```

And if `div.one` and `div.two` are always there, use:

```
this.fetchText('div.ma-AdCardMyAds:nth-child('+i+') > div.one > div.two span[class="ma-AdCard-price"]')
```